# ZMQ Raw TX doesn't include all transactions

Tags: raw-transaction, zeromq

I'm running a Bitcore.io node and using their ZMQ hook but I've noticed that on livenet not all transactions are actually being sent. I've been comparing it to https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions and my realtime logs and can see that some don't appear.

I've also tried creating a transaction to a output address and notifying us of this when it occurs and it hasn't appeared indicating my suspicions are correct.

This only happens on livenet, ran all our tests on testnet and it worked perfectly. Could this have something to do with `maxconnections`? I've tried increasing it to `250`

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of how many messages can be in the ZMQ:

http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-setsockopt

> The ZMQ_HWM option shall set the high water mark for the specified socket. The high water mark is a hard limit on the maximum number of outstanding messages ØMQ shall queue in memory for any single peer that the specified socket is communicating with.

So you might need to specify the option `-zmqpubrawtxhwm` to something that is larger than the default of 1000.

Comment: The question is not about Bitcoin Core. It's about bitcore.io.